# Controller Design in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I'm trying to follow some best practices outlined here:

http://trochette.github.io/Angular-Design-Patterns-Best-Practices/#/inheritance_pattern

And building my controller like so

CompanyController.js

```
var CompanyController = BaseController.extend({
    $http: null, 

    init: function($scope, $http, companies) {
        $scope.update = this.onQuery;
        $scope.companies = companies;
        $scope.ctrl = this; //is this advisable?

        this.$http = $http;
    },
    onQuery: function() {
        //context is $scope so $http is not available, need
        // to use this.ctrl
        this.ctrl.$http.get(...).then(...);
    }
});
```

And then in the view  I have

```
<input ng-model="query" ng-change="update()" />
```

What's the best practice as far as keeping a handle on the controller / $http variables in the update method? In jQuery I used to use $.proxy(...) - but I get the sense that is not the Angular way.

Also adding the ctrl reference to $scope smells funny to me and I'm wondering if I'm not going to get stuck down the line..

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Not sure I completely understand the question, but the angular way would be to move your data access into a service, and then use that service

Comment: Did you mean to delete your answer?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure it was entirely correct and it didn't answer both parts of your question.